# How can I pass a function template as (template) argument to a function template?

Tags: c++, templates

Currently, I have a code like

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template<std::uint32_t idx>
void f() {
    std::cout << "f(" << idx << ")\n";
}

template<std::uint32_t n>
void loop1() {
    f<n>();
    if constexpr (n > 0) {
        loop1<n - 1>();
    }
}

template<std::uint32_t idx>
void g() {
    std::cout << "g(" << idx << ")\n";
}

template<std::uint32_t n>
void loop2() {
    g<n>();
    if constexpr (n > 0) {
        loop2<n - 1>();
    }
}

int main() {
    loop1<4>();
    loop2<2>();
}
```

It's necessary for `f`, `g`, `loop1` and `loop2` to be function templates. Now, I have to add more functions, but `loop1` and `loop2` will always be the same, a recursive template loop.

How can I pass the function template as (template) argument to `loop` to achieve something like:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template<std::uint32_t idx>
void f() {
    std::cout << "f(" << idx << ")\n";
}

template<std::uint32_t idx>
void g() {
    std::cout << "g(" << idx << ")\n";
}

template<std::uint32_t n, typename h>
void loop() {
    h<n>();
    if constexpr (n > 0) {
        loop<n - 1, h>();
    }
}

int main() {
    loop<4, h>();
    loop<2, h>();
}
```

I prefer to pass the function as template argument at compile time, but a solution to pass the function template as function argument at runtime would also solve my problem, e.g.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template<std::uint32_t idx>
void f() {
    std::cout << "f(" << idx << ")\n";
}

template<std::uint32_t idx>
void g() {
    std::cout << "g(" << idx << ")\n";
}

template<std::uint32_t n, typename T>
void loop(T h) {
    h<n>();
    if constexpr (n > 0) {
        loop<n - 1>(h);
    }
}

int main() {
    loop<4>(h);
    loop<2>(h);
}
```

or

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template<std::uint32_t idx>
void f() {
    std::cout << "f(" << idx << ")\n";
}

template<std::uint32_t idx>
void g() {
    std::cout << "g(" << idx << ")\n";
}

template<std::uint32_t n, template<std::uint32_t> typename F>
void loop(F h) {
    h<n>();
    if constexpr (n > 0) {
        loop<n - 1>(h);
    }
}

int main() {
    loop<4>(h);
    loop<2>(h);
}
```

Is this even possible? I know, that all of my approaches are wrong syntax. It's just to illustrate, what I want to achieve.

Comment: It is not possible to pass a "function template" as argument. See [Why can't template functions be passed as a template template parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56904980/why-cant-template-functions-be-passed-as-a-template-template-parameter)

Comment: @JasonLiam Is it possible to achieve, what I want? I'd like to reuse `loop` for two different function templates. It doesn't have to be a template argument.

Comment: You should write what is the expected output and how it differs from your current output.

Comment: The output in the first code snippet is correct and it's the expected output. I want to remove `loop2` and reuse `loop1` for both cases, because it's code duplication and I have to add many of these duplicate function templates now. The goal is to have many function templates `f`, `g`, `h`, ... and use them in the same function template `loop`.

Comment: @JasonLiam I think you answered my question. I'll try to replace the function templates with functors/class templates.

Comment: Damn, I had an answer almost finished for you @jabaa

Comment: I was in the middle of writing an answer how to work around this, but it was gold-closed. Great!

Comment: instead of functions, you can use functors with the same functionality (they can even call your functions) https://godbolt.org/z/975oceqdr

Comment: You can vote to reopen :)

Comment: @Fareanor Yeah, like that ever works ...

Comment: @bitmask You were two, I would gladly add the third vote for you. If you can be less unpleasant, it would be appreciated though (and be much of a help)

Comment: @Fareanor Sorry, I did not mean to be unfriendly towards anybody or you in particular. I'm just a bit frustrated because lately I see a lot of questions being dupe-closed despite not being duplicates but merely tangentially related to the proposed duplicate.

Comment: @bitmask I get your point, no worries :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this with free functions but you can do something similar to what you want to have with class template static member functions:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template<std::uint32_t idx>
struct F {
  static void function() {
    std::cout << "f(" << idx << ")\n";
  }
};

template<std::uint32_t idx>
struct G {
  static void function() {
    std::cout << "g(" << idx << ")\n";
  }
};

template<std::uint32_t n, template<std::uint32_t> typename T>
void loop() {
    T<n>::function();
    if constexpr (n > 0) {
        loop<n - 1, T>();
    }
}

int main() {
    loop<4, F>();
    loop<2, G>();
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4Mqe6evjs).

Answer (score 2):

For this I would recommend a either a generic or a template lambda. The goal of our solution would be to send in a predicate that can receive the parameter `idx` at compile time.

With template lambda (C++20):

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template<std::uint32_t idx>
void f() {
    std::cout << "f(" << idx << ")\n";
}

template<std::uint32_t idx>
void g() {
    std::cout << "g(" << idx << ")\n";
}

template<std::uint32_t n, typename F>
void loop(F h) {
    h.template operator()<n>();
    if constexpr (n > 0) {
        loop<n - 1>(h);
    }
}

int main() {
    loop<4>([]<std::uint32_t idx>() {
        return f<idx>();
    });
    loop<2>([]<std::uint32_t idx>() {
        return g<idx>();
    });
}
```

This is the closest solution to what you posted. The lambda there is a type with a templated `operator()`.

---

With generic lambda (compatible with C++14)

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template<std::uint32_t idx>
void f() {
    std::cout << "f(" << idx << ")\n";
}

template<std::uint32_t idx>
void g() {
    std::cout << "g(" << idx << ")\n";
}

template<std::uint32_t n, typename F>
void loop(F h) {
    h(std::integral_constant<std::uint32_t, n>{});
    if constexpr (n > 0) {
        loop<n - 1>(h);
    }
}

int main() {
    loop<4>([](auto idx) {
        return f<idx>();
    });
    loop<2>([](auto idx) {
        return g<idx>();
    });
}
```

This solution is using generic lambdas, but is still a templated lambda in reality. `idx` is taking the type of `std::integral_constant` which can be sent as template parameter since its conversion operator to `std::uint32_t` is constexpr.

Answer (score 1):

I would replace the template functions `f` and `g` by structs `F` and `G` respectively, each one with a template method `invoke`:

```
struct F {
  template<std::uint32_t idx>
  void invoke() {
    std::cout << "f(" << idx << ")\n";
  }
};

struct G {
  template<std::uint32_t idx>
  void invoke() {
    std::cout << "g(" << idx << ")\n";
  }
};

template<std::uint32_t n, typename F>
void loop(F h) {
    h.template invoke<n>();
    if constexpr (n > 0) {
        loop<n - 1>(h);
    }
}
```

Nothing stops you from adding template functions `f` and `g` that call `invoke` for `F` and `G` respectively:

```
template<std::uint32_t idx>
void f() {
  F().invoke<idx>();
}

template<std::uint32_t idx>
void g() {
  G().invoke<idx>();
}
```